# JavaScript constructor and prototype object

Tags: javascript

I am curious as to what's going on here.  As you can see, I have defined a constructor function called `range` to build new `range` objects.  I've extended the `range` constructor through it's prototype, adding a simple `includes` method.  I've created my new object and used the variable of `p`.  When I attempt to use this method with my `range` objects, all is well and it works as expected.  The problem is when I try to look at at `p.prototype` it tells me that it's type is undefined and `p.prototype` has no methods...  Huh??

What's going on here??  How is `p` an object and `p.prototype` is not?

```
    function range(from, to) {
        this.from = from;
        this.to = to;
    }


    range.prototype = {
        includes: function(x) { return this.from <= x && x <= this.to; },
    }

    var p = new range(1, 4);

    console.log(typeof p) //outputs object
    console.log(typeof p.prototype) //outputs undefined

    console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(range.prototype)); //outputs includes
    console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(p.prototype)); //throws error, p.prototype is not an object
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The problem is when I try to look at at `p.prototype` it tells me that it's type is undefined

That's correct. The objects created by your `range` constructor do not have a `prototype` property, but they do have an underlying prototype (which is drawn from the `prototype` property of the `range` function).

Let's look at what happens when you do `new range()`:

1. The JavaScript engine creates a new, blank object.
2. The JavaScript engine assigns that object's underlying prototype (not `prototype`) to be the object referenced by `range.prototype`. (In the spec, this property — which is not *directly* accessible in code but see below — is called `[[Proto]]`.)
3. The JavaScript engine calls `range` with `this` referring to the new object.
4. Assuming `range` doesn't return a *different* object (which it can do; this is a bit obscure), the result of `new range` is the new object created in step 1.

Later, when you use `this.includes`, this is what happens:

1. The engine looks at the actual object to see if it has an `includes` property.
2. Since it doesn't, the engine looks at `[[Proto]]` to see if *it* has one.
3. Since it does, it uses that one (if not, it would have looked at `[[Proto]]`'s `[[Proto]]` and so on).

The key things here are:

1. Objects have underlying prototypes, which are not accessible via any named property on the object itself. (In fact, it used to be we couldn't get to them ***at all***. Now, in ES5, we have [`Object.getPrototypeOf`](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.2.3.2).)
2. Objects created via `new SomeFunctionName` get their prototype from `SomeFunctionName.prototype` property, which is a perfectly normal property of the `SomeFunctionName` object (functions are first-class objects in JavaScript).

---

Side note: You're *replacing* the `prototype` of `range` with your code. In general, although it works, I would avoid that. Instead, *augment* the existing object referred to by `range.prototype`. (Add properties to it, rather than replacing it.) But that's not central to your question.

Comment: Well, how am I able to use any of these methods defined in `range.prototype` if `p` has no `prototype`?

Comment: @SethenMaleno: By simply referring to them from `p` (e.g., `p.includes`).

Comment: read this article - http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/06/07/understanding-javascript-prototypes/ - will be very useful.

Comment: The fundamental idea to grok here is that, in Javascript, there are no classes.  Objects inherit from other objects.

Comment: How am I replacing the `prototype` with what I have at the top?  The reason I wrote it that way was to extend it with a lot of different methods.

Comment: And, if I have read this correctly, you're telling me that I can not see the `prototype` object of new objects created through constructors, yes?

Comment: @SethenMaleno: *"How am I replacing the prototype with what I have at the top?"* You're assigning a new object to `range.prototype`, completely replacing the reference to any object that it used to refer to. Instead of `range.prototype = { includes: ... };`, use `range.prototype.includes = ...`.

Comment: @SethenMaleno: *"And, if I have read this correctly, you're telling me that I can not see the prototype object of new objects created through constructors, yes?"* You can as of ES5, via `Object.getPropertyOf`. Previously, you could not. You could only infer their contents by seeing what properties an object had that were not "own" properties (e.g., for which `hasOwnProperty` returned false). If `hasOwnProperty` returns false but an object has that property (you can tell via `for/in` or the `in` operator), then the property must come from the prototype. But again, ES5 gives us something direct.

Answer (score 0):

I think you wanted was:

```
range.prototype.includes = function(x) { 
    return this.from <= x && x <= this.to; 
}
```

Comment: I am not sure how this is any different than I have it.  I have written it to define multiple methods in an the prototype object.

Comment: This still throws errors.  Not sure how this answers my question.

Comment: While it's true that Sethen is replacing the prototype, that's a perfectly valid thing to do (though I don't recommend it) and is not the source of the behavior he's seeing. Also, `from` and `to` were never part of the prototype ***at all***. They were (and remain) parts of the objects created via `new range`. The fact that Sethen is replacing the prototype has exactly no effect on them.

Comment: The same ones outlined in the original question.

Comment: I think T.J. Crowder has laid it out for you pretty clearly.  You can call `Object.getOwnPropertyNames(p.prototype)`.  It is supposed to give you an error.

Answer (score 0):

You redefined the prototype object, so the reference to the original one has disappeared. Try this way:

```
range.prototype.includes = function(x) { 
    return this.from <= x && x <= this.to;
}
```

Comment: While this is true, it's not the source of the behavior in question.

Answer (score 0):

```
Number.prototype.myRound = function (decimalPlaces) {
    var multiplier = Math.pow(10, decimalPlaces);

    return (Math.round(this * multiplier) / multiplier);
};
```